# In Scala, how can I pass null to a Java method that expects Long?

Tags: java, scala, interop, null

I have a Java method that accepts a Long value:

```
(in Java)
public void setValue(Long value);
```

I understand that the Scala null does not extend any of the value types, including Long. Therefore, when I try to pass null to it, I get a compilation error:

```
(in Scala)
javaThing.setValue(null)

==> type mismatch; found  : Any required: java.lang.Long
```

**EDIT: aargh! Ignore above snippet. I oversimplified the problem, and got into trouble. In fact, problem arises from my use of Option[Long], as follows:**

```
javaThing.setValue(calcValue.getOrElse(null))
```

The issue is, I think, that getOrElse evaluates to the Any type when given a null argument.

Help!

Comment: lol I can't think of a faster way to get to the top of a google hit list in 13 minutes than asking a question on stackoverflow: http://www.google.com/search?q=pass+null+to+java+method+that+expects+long&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=gqc&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&q=pass+null+to+method+expecting+long&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=d6f0dac0a9f1050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce that here.

JavaTst.java:

```
public class JavaTst {
    public void setValue(Long value) {}
}
```

REPL:

```
scala> new JavaTst
res0: JavaTst = JavaTst@4e229e

scala> res0.setValue(null)

scala>
```

**EDIT**

Aha! In that case, this convoluted code will work:

```
res0.setValue(calcValue.map(new java.lang.Long(_)).getOrElse(null))
```

I suggest importing java.lang.Long to jlLong, to keep it shorter.

Comment: The problem seems to be when you define the method in Scala: scala> class JavaTst() { def setValue(value: Long) {} }
defined class JavaTst

scala> new JavaTst
res4: JavaTst = JavaTst@4fb529d6

scala> res4.setValue(null)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Long
       res4.setValue(null)
                     ^

Comment: You are perfectly correct. I've corrected my faulty description of the problem, which has to do with the use of Option[Long]. Apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't understand the solution with calcValue.map(new java.lang.Long(_); what's going on there?

Comment: @David Scala's `Long` is an `AnyVal`, and, therefore, does not have `null` as a possible value. So I'm mapping it to a `java.lang.Long`, which does. Once that is accomplished, then Scala can infer the type `java.lang.Long` for `null`, which it couldn't for `Long`.

Answer (score 11):

Explicitly casting using `asInstanceOf` will work:

```
scala> val l:java.lang.Long = Some(2L).getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long]
l: java.lang.Long = 2

scala> val n:java.lang.Long = None.getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long]    
n: java.lang.Long = null
```

So, something like this should work:

```
javaThing.setValue(calcValue.getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Long])
```

It's subverting the type-system, but so is using `null` in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Or even shorter:

```
null.asInstanceOf[Long]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there isn't a way beyond choosing a value of long to work like null. Usually it's -1 that gets used.

Answer (score 0):

use .orNull:

javaThing.setValue(calcValue.orNull)